# Inserting random numbers from 1 to $n^2$ in a matrix of size $n \times n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, matrices, random-variables, random-matrices

I have two matrices of size nxn with random numbers that are in range of $1$ to $n^2$.
I'm trying to calculate the probability of :

1. the numbers 1 and 9 are present in the same indices in the two matrices,for example($n=4$):
   \begin{bmatrix}
       14& 10 & 2  & 1 \\
       11& \textbf{1} & 16 & 15 \\
       4 & 9& 13 & \textbf{9}\\
       6 & 3& 5 & 7\\
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
       13& 4& 2  & 7 \\
       15& \textbf{1} & 11& 10\\
       6 & 16& 5& \textbf{9}\\
       12 & 8& 3 & 14\\
   \end{bmatrix}
2. A pair (one or more) of two numbers that are sequential that exist in the same index of the two matrices.
   for example(n=4):
   \begin{bmatrix}
       14& 10 & 2  & 1 \\
       11& 1 & 16 & 15 \\
       4 & 9& 13 & \textbf{6}\\
       6 & 3& \textbf{5} & 7\\
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
       13& 4& 2  & 7 \\
       15& 3 & 11& 10\\
       6 & 16& 2& \textbf{6}\\
       12 & 8& \textbf{5} & 14\\
   \end{bmatrix}
3. Row values of the first matrix are equal to the row values of the second matrix (not necessarily in the same index values) ,example(n=4):
   \begin{bmatrix}
       14& 10 & 2  & 8 \\
       11& 1 & 16 & 15 \\
       4 & 12& 9& 6\\
       13 & 3& 5 & 7\\
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
       10& 2& 8  & 14 \\
       16& 11 & 15& 1\\
       6 & 9& 4& 12\\
       13 & 3& 7 & 5\\
   \end{bmatrix}

Comment: "with random numbers that are in range of $1$ to $ n^2$" ... that seems to say the numbers are drawn (independently) in that range, but from the examples (no repetitions) I guess you meant that the matrix are filled with a random permutation of those numbers, is that so?

Comment: Yes numbers are drawn independently and are inserted in the matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'll solve the first part of the problem and leave the rest for you to solve**

First place 1 and 9 at any two locations out of $n^2$ available locations. Then fill the rest of $2n^2-4$ with any number between 1 and $n^2$. So the total number of desired possibilities $=^{n^2}\!\!\!P_{2}(n^2)^{2n^2-4}$.

The number of possible matrix pairs without any restrictions is  $(n^2)^{2n^2}$.

Hence the probability is $\frac{n^2-1}{n^6}$

Comment: Could you do the second one also ? I have tried to approach this by defining the negation of the desired outcome and subtracting from 1 but I'm not succeeding

Comment: I don't understand the $^{n^2}\!\!\!P_{2}(n^2)^{2n^2-4}$ formula did you permutate $n^2$ numbers in $2(n^2)^{2n^2-4}$ places ?

Comment: There are $2n^2-4$ places to be filled, and each of them has $n^2$ possibilities. Hence, the total number of possibilities is $(n^2)^{2n^2-4}$.

Comment: Show me your try for the second and the third parts, and I can help you. for the second part, there is no need to define the negation. Just that 1 and 9 will get replaced by one from the possible $n-1$ pairs of consecutive numbers.